# Using $wpdb object in a widget

Tags: plugin-development, widgets, wpdb, shared-user-tables

I'm trying to make a very simple widget that access tables contained within the same database instance as my Wordpress database, but are not wordpress tables. I'm using the [wpdb class according to the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpdb_Class). I'm not getting any errors, but I'm also not getting any results.

Am I using the object appropriately? Or should I be rolling my own access class for my own tables?

Here is the widget code:

```
function widget ($args,$instance) 
{
        extract($args);

        global $wpdb;

        $title = $instance['title'];
        $catid = $instance['catid'];

        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

        $sql = 'SELECT max(ID) as MaxID, status FROM Clients WHERE UserID = '.$current_user->ID;
        $clientRow = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

        $out = '<div style="text-align: center; border: solid 1px Navy; background-color: #E4E4E4">';
        $out .= '<span>Client status: '.$clientRow->status.'</span></div>';

        echo $before_widget;
        echo $before_title.$title.$after_title;
        echo $out;
        echo $after_widget;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any chance of seeing the code? :)

Comment: Yepp, hard to tell if we can't see what you're doing.

Comment: How foolish of me! I posted the code now. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really just want a single row, use `$wpdb->get_row($sql)` instead.

But your query looks funny...it looks like you're trying to get the latest 'client status' for the user in which case your query should be:
`'SELECT status FROM Clients WHERE UserID = '.$current_user->ID.' ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1'`.

And if you do that, you can then even use `$status = $wpdb->get_var($sql);`.

Lastly...did you consider using add_user_meta/get_user_meta instead? There's a lot of benefits to using the native tables and functions, such as that the records get cleaned up when you delete the user and the likes.

Comment: The meta stuff will come in handy in other aspects of the site, but I do require ancillary tables in this case. Thank  you for your solution. It is concise, and most importantly functional.

Answer (score 2):

[`$wpdb->get_results()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpdb_Class#SELECT_Generic_Results) returns multiple rows as an array of objects (or an array of arrays, depending on the `$output` parameter). What you want is [`$wpdb->get_row()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpdb_Class#SELECT_a_Row).

Answer (score 1):

Your results will come back as an array of objects, not a singular object..

This line treats the result as an object.

```
$clientRow->status
```

When in fact you've got an array with objects, this would reference the first.

```
$clientRow[0]->status
```

Not sure quite what you're expecting from the result, so hopefully the above info is enough to help fix the problem?

Small note, you may not need this..

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
```

Giving `$current_user` scope should be enough.